# Using a String to evaluate enum?

Tags: java, eclipse, enums, constants

I am trying to use a String to evaluate whether or not the strings contents are equal to the enum type I have declared. However I am getting an error in Eclipse trying to force me to create nameOfMonth as an enum constant. Rather than write code to specifically declare January as #1, February as #2, and so forth it seemed easier to me to use enum. Is there a way I can use a user defined String and compare it to my enums? For example in the code below if the parameter String nameOfMonth was equal to January I would like it to pull the index location and add one.

Here is the code:

```
    package ProgrammingChallenges;

public class Month
{
    enum MONTH
    {
        January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December
    }

    private int monthNumber;

    public Month()
    {
        monthNumber = 1;
    }

    public Month(int monthNumber)
    {
        if (monthNumber < 1 || monthNumber > 12)
            this.monthNumber = 1;
        else
            this.monthNumber = monthNumber;

    }

    public Month(String nameOfMonth)
    {
        if(nameOfMonth.equals(MONTH.nameOfMonth))
            this.monthNumber = namOfMonth.ordinal() + 1;
    }

}
```

Comment: By the way, there is such an enum now built into Java 8 and later: [`java.time.Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Month.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public Month(String nameOfMonth)
{
        this.monthNumber = Enum.valueOf(MONTH, nameOfMonth).ordinal() + 1;
}
```

According to the [Enum javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29), this will throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if the user passes an invalid string, which seems like a fitting error. (Note that `MONTH.valueOf(str)` simply calls `Enum.valueOf(MONTH, str)`).

However, I don't see why you even need a separate Month class. Why don't you just change `Month` to an `enum` instead? Even if you have extra methods on this class, you should be able to add those to the enum just like you have in your current class implementation. Technically Java enums are just special cases of classes with a private constructor and a statically-defined set of instances, so you should be able to do everything you want with the enum.

Instead of your current constructors, you would use `Month.January` in the "default" case, `Month.values()[i-1]` for the case when you want to get the month by index, and `Month.valueOf(str)` for the case when you use a string. You could also add static helper methods to your enum that wraps each of these cases. Here's what I'm picturing:

```
public enum Month {
    January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December;

    public static Month getDefault() {
        return January;
    }

    public static Month fromNumber(int monthNumber) {
        try {
            return Month.values()[monthNumber-1];
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            return getDefault();
        }
    }

    public static Month fromString(String nameOfMonth) {
        try {
            return valueOf(nameOfMonth);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return getDefault();
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a comment on Simon's answer?

Comment: Why use `Enum.valueOf` when you can simply use ´MONTH.valueOf`?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg - It avoids an extra method call. The `MONTH.valueOf` just passes its argument through to `Enum.valueOf`. You can easily check this with `javap`. However, the JIT compiler is probably smart enough to inline that, so now that I think about it, it probably wouldn't make a real difference.

Comment: So I suppose I should do a check to make sure it's a valid enum before passing the argument? Or is this method bad practice in general?

Comment: @SamHenderson Yes, check before to make sure it is a valid enum. This method in itself is not bad practice.

Comment: @SamHenderson - You could do a check beforehand, or just catch the `InvalidArgumentException` thrown if it isn't. Also, check my edit. I think refactoring a bit and adding static helper methods would do a lot of good here.

Comment: @DaoWen I thank you for the improved Month class. The reason why I am doing it this way is because it is simply a programming challenge in a book and the instruction are to create a class month. I only chose to use enum as I thought it would be the best way.

Answer (score 4):

## `Enum.valueOf`

You can use the [`valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf(java.lang.Class,java.lang.String)) method of your enum.

```
public Month(String nameOfMonth)
{
   this.monthNumber = MONTH.valueOf(nameOfMonth).ordinal() + 1;
}
```

There is no need for the if-statement here, just use Java's built-in `valueOf` static method for enums directly to get an enum corresponding to the string. If `nameOfMonth` doesn't match an enum, it will throw an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.yourclass.yourenum.the_invalid_enum_name
    at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score -1):

For those who are interested this is how I ended up solving my issue. I couldn't have done it without all of your great answers!

```
MONTH[] months = MONTH.values();

for (MONTH m : months)
        if (m.toString().equals(nameOfMonth))
            this.monthNumber = MONTH.valueOf(nameOfMonth).ordinal() + 1;
```

Comment: This loops through all enum-values which is not necessary.